# Python regular expression operation

Tags: python

I would like to split the data by `;`, excluding the `;` inside `()`. For example I have the string like this:

```
string = "Axxx;Bxxx;Cxxx;D(xx;xx)"
```

What I hope the output is:

```
output = ["Axxx", "Bxxx"; "Cxxx"; "D(xx;xx)"]
```

I found a solution:

```
output = re.split('\;\s*(?![^()]*\))',string)
```

It works and I checked the `re` documentation, but I still don't know how or why it works. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be alternative solutions, even without re, but here is my breakdown
for re.split

`split` function from `re`, splits string on any character sequesnces that match a pattern, not just one given symbol or string

Let's break down the pattern

`\;` - separator  is semicolon (slash means escape, it prevents a confusion with special codes)

`\s*` - possibly followed by  spaces or other whitespace characters, you do not need it for your example, yet it does not hurt

`(?!` - *negative lookahead* assertion. It imposes addtional restrictions, on which semicolons to split string and which to ignore. *Lookahead* means do not not include the part of the string that matches subpattern inside of `(?! ... )`  into separator, *negative* implies that to be considered separator a semicolon should *not* be followed by prohibited sequences. Namely a possibly empty sequence (`*`) of non brackets `[^()]` followed by a closing bracket `\)` precludes the break. (such as `xx)` in your example. But It would be ok have expression after semicolon which has opening and closing bracket (in your case `D(xx;xx)`. Basically lookahead forbids you to break inside a pair of matching parenteses.

The full list of regex expressions can be found in official docs, but read some tutorial if you find it difficult to read or understand.

I believe in a previous post I have seen a simpler solution with `re.findall` which does not requires the lookahead.

PS. Sometimes you get unwanted emptystrings with re.split, remember to filter out them

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Similarly, I use the same approach to split the string by `=`, excluding `=` inside `" "` and I try `output = re.split('\=\s*(?![^\"\"]*\))',string)`. Why this time can't work?

Comment: Do you have = in your string?

Comment: Yes. My string look like `"Axxx=Bxxx=Cxxx=D"xx=xx""` and I would like to split to `["Axxx", "Bxxx", "Cxxx", "D"xx=xx""]`

Comment: you cannot have quotations inside double quoted string

Comment: must escape D\"xxx=\"xx or use single quotes

Comment: https://bic-berkeley.github.io/psych-214-fall-2016/string_literals.html

Comment: Yes you are correct. The string should look like `'Axxx=Bxxx=Cxxx=D"xx=xx"'` and I would like to split to `['Axxx', 'Bxxx', 'Cxxx', 'D"xx=xx"']`

Comment: It should be a double quotation inside single quotation

Comment: because there is no opening and closing quotation in python. The solution is valid only if you have opening and closing brackets.

Comment: also there is not closing bracket in your string but there is one in regex \\)

Comment: findall('([A-Z]+([a-z]+|(\"[a-z=]+\")))')